# Map static resource to specific URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to map my `login.html` to `/login` URL.

I tried `<mvc:resources ... />` and `ResourceHandlerRegistry` but they use wildcards and require URL to match filename. I want to be able to map specific url to specific file, something like:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/login" location="/static/login.html"/>
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Beside creating a controller and writing file content to response stream manually.

Comment: Use Apache tiles and use different layouts on your specific urls. it not that hard and very neat http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-apache-tiles-3-annotation-based-example/ worth to try.

Comment: @Boldbayar Thank you for suggestion, this is quite similar to the trick I use now, which is `Freemarker` + `<mvc:view-controller ... >`. The downside is that I have to depend on Freemarker(Tiles) despite having no templates.

Comment: I'm surprised that `<mvc:view-controller>` doesn't work alone. Maybe it requires to configure `ViewResolver` also?

Comment: It does, I was not able to figure out which one to use. Frankly im not sure this is correct approach since static HTML is not exactly a view.